# slow memory release (refcounted structure) - Is my workaround a good way?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, refcounting

in my program i can load a Catalog: ICatalog

a Catalog here contains a lot of refcounted structures (Icollections of IItems, IElements, IRules, etc.)

when I want to change to another catalog,
I load a new Catalog
but the automatic release of the previous ICatalog instance takes time, freezing my application for 2 second or more.

my question is :

I want to defer the release of the old (and no more used) ICatalog instance to another thread.

I've not tested it already, but I intend to create a new thread with :

```
ErazerThread.OldCatalog := Catalog; // old catalog refcount jumps to 2
Catalog := LoadNewCatalog(...);     // old catalog refcount =1
ErazerThread.Execute;               //just set OldCatalog to nil.
```

this way, I expect the release to occur in the thread, and my application not 
beeing freezed anymore.

Is it safe (and good practice) ?
Do you have examples of existing code already perfoming release with a similar method ?

Comment: One other thing to watch out for is the possibility that your object has some affinity to the thread which created it.

Comment: Did you use a profiler and find out WHY the free code takes so long? Heap operations alone are probably NOT causing your problem unless you're freeing 1.8 gb of memory, 100 bytes at a time.

Comment: @WarrenP Using sampling profiler, and wrapping the release with OutputDebugString('SAMPLING ON'); (and OFF), I found out that 95,05 % of the time occurs in ntdll.dll... this has no useful meaning for me.. (then, can the analysis of the remaining 4,54% in my executable be interesting for optimisation ?)

Comment: Warren P: isn't COM memory management slower than native? This is about interfaces allocations. Don't know how much slower though.

Comment: @DamienD: I'm surprised that memory allocation is taking so much time inside ntdll.dll.  It must be swapping heavily?  How much physical RAM do you have?

Comment: @Warren : no swapping seems to occurs. (2 Go) Moreover, Freeing in another thread isn't working. I found more information from sampling profiler [see image](http://www.screencast.com/users/Idea/folders/Default/media/38d636f1-6eca-4359-a6e1-db98dd0fd738) using "show callers".  I think I have to re-consider my own Collection classes implementation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would let such thread block on some threadsafe queue(*), and push the interfaces to release into that queue as iunknowns.

Note however that if the releasing touches a lock that your memory manager uses (like a global heapmanager lock), then this is futile, since your mainthread will block on the first heapmanager access.

With a heapmanager with per thread pools, allocating many items in one thread and releasing it in a different thread might frustrate coalescing and reuse of (small) blocks algorithms.

I still think the way you describe is generally sound when implemented properly. But 
this is from a theoretic perspective to show that there might be a link from the 2nd thread to the mainthread via the heapmanager.

(*) Simplest way is to add it to a tthreadlist and use tevent to signal that an element was added.

Comment: I see your point, but concerning threads and low level memory management, i'm, hum, a beginner... correct me if 'm wrong : a global heapmanager lock can be caused by a threadsafe Object ? (i mean, the use of critical sections ?)

Comment: A threadsafe object  is passed to the memorymanager when released. The memorymanager can be called from multiple threads thus has locks. Maybe I should summarize the answer like this: "If walking the tree and ref counting and destructors turn out to be the main slowing factor, than pushing to a thread might help. If it is the work done on freeing in the heapmanager (or the calls to COM if they are COM objects) it might not"

Comment: tried it. pushing to a thread does not help in my case (see my comment under my question). thanks for explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

That looks OK, but don't call the thread's `Execute` method directly; that will run the thread object's code in the *current* thread instead of the one that the thread object creates. Call `Start` or `Resume` instead.